# The name 'collection' is already registered for this blueprint. Use 'name=' to provide a unique name. This will become an error in Flask 2.1

Tags: python, flask

```
from collection import collection_api

app.register_blueprint(collection_api, url_prefix="/typing-session")
app.register_blueprint(collection_api, url_prefix="/api/dataservice/typing-session)
```

It is already created, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to register the same Blueprint twice.

Change the second line to `app.register_blueprint(collection_api, name="<some_unique_name>", url_prefix="/api/dataservice/typing-session)`

Comment: I get the same error message now, but I am not explicitly registering things twice... it seems like something about the import machinery doing something weird